# update relationship between two nodes if one exists, or create a new relationship if one does not already exist NEO4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to write a query that;

- updates a relationship between two nodes if one already exists, or
- if a relationsihp doesnt exist create one between the two nodes.

In reality this is to allow one user of a program, to 'block' another user of the program, regardless of whether or not the two users previously had any sort of a relationship (there could any number of them). 
For one half of the query, optionally returning a relationship if one exists;

```
MATCH (a:user {name: {aParam}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (a) -[r]- (b:user {name: {bParam}) 
RETURN type(r), a
```

For the other half of the query, updating a relationship between two nodes (given that it already exists);

```
MATCH (a:user {name: {aParam}) <- [r:originalRelationship] - (b:user {name: {bParam})
WITH a, r, b
MERGE (a) - [:updatedRelationship] - (b)
WITH r
DELETE r
```

But combing the two I havent generated a working example, I tried combining them together but frankenstein didn't come to life;

```
MATCH (a:user {name: {aParam})
OPTIONAL MATCH (a) - [r] - (b:user {name: {bParam})
WITH a, b, r
MERGE (a) - [:block] -> (b)
WITH r
DELETE r
```

Can someone point out my errors here and point me in the right direction?

Comment: Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError: org.neo4j.values.storable.NoValue cannot be cast to org.neo4j.values.virtual.NodeValue is there error I get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have multiple relationships involved and you want to remove all existing relationships and replace them with Blocked, you can try this:

```
Match (p1:Person{name:"hj"}),(p2:Person{name:"bg"})
OPTIONAL Match (p1)-[r]->(p2) where TYPE(r)<>"Blocked"
MERGE (p1)-[:Blocked{blocked: True}]->(p2)
DELETE r
return *
```

Keeping the below part in case it helps someone. If you only have 1 type of relationship, and just want to update values, you can use this:

You can use **Merge** clause with **ON MATCH** and **ON CREATE** options.

Since you haven't clearly specified the nodes and relation structure, I will give another example.
Considering 2 Person nodes where the field "name" uniquely identifies the person.

The query creates the relationship if not present, and if it is already present, you can specify the fields you want to update.

```
Match (p1:Person{name:"hj"}),(p2:Person{name:"bg"})
Merge (p1)-[r:originalRelationship]->(p2)
ON CREATE SET r.created = True
ON MATCH SET r.updated = True
return p1,p2,r
```

Comment: sorry, i updated my question to clarify. nodes are of the same type/label. there can be at most 1 relationship between any two nodes, but that relationship can be of various types, or there could be no relationship between two nodes at all of course.

Comment: i dont think this answers my question though, my question is create a 'blocked' relationship from one node to another, if there was no relationship between the two nodes before, or delete the original relationshp if one existed and replace it with a 'blocked' relationship

Comment: @user74091 please check the updated answer and see if that works for you. It deletes creates "Block" relation and should delete all other relations if any exist.

Comment: Ok it looks like what I need, will try when I get back to my computer

Comment: You included a property on the blocked relationship, {blocked: True}, is that a necessity or is that preference? Can you comment on the use of properties here please?

Comment: No that's not necessary. If you want to add additional information to the property, you can use any relationship properties. Its your choice.